# What can we do about so many exit nodes being marked as spammers?

Tags: exit-relays, email

I have noticed that when I try to sign up for things that require an email address over Tor, I am almost always blocked from doing so and told that I am a spammer. I believe that the cause of that is that the exit relays are being marked as spammers, either because someone has been spamming a lot over Tor or some spam identification system has a problem with Tor (I am assuming the former).

Is there anything we can do to fix this?

Comment: It appears that the entire listing of exit relays are being blocked, whether they've been used for spam or not. What really gets me is that the IRC for Tor doesn't accept connections from Tor relays.